# Accessing variables of the wrapper object in OOP

Tags: java, vba, application-design

I am creating an application in VBA for my employer (and a similar one in Java for hobby purposes) and its purpose is to 'contain' different tools that will help in our daily work. It's going to be some kind of platform with the main app window and from there a user can access some of the application components like for instance a sub-program when a user can give me feedback on application's functionality, then the info will be stored in a database that I can access later.

I already have a structure: an Application class, that contains the Application Manager and this one class contain an array of fields of the SubApp type. A SubApp type contains view, logic, and business of a sub-application. The Application class also contains members like the name of the app and the information about the user that is currently using the app (previously accessed from the application database).

Whenever a sub-app launch, I would like to put on the title bar the name of the app as well as the name of the sub-app, something like application_name - sub_app_name. The problem is, that I have no idea how can I access it the 'right way'. Recently I've achieved this by creating the app variable as a global object, then accessing it is no problem using some getters. I feel however that storing an application variable as a global variable is a bad practice.

The same problem occurs with the member variable storing info about the current user. I'd like to store the information about the current user while he's giving feedback (tool for giving a feedback is a sub-app in my application)

So here is my question: how can I access the methods/variables of a wrapping object from within one of the member methods/variables?

Any suggestions regarding the overall design of the application would also be welcome.

Comment: Sounds like you want to apply the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example), GoF give *Represent an operation to be performed on elements of an object structure. Visitor lets you define a new operation without changing the classes of the elements on which it operates.*.

Comment: provide code and this sounds like more code review than a problem

Comment: Without the code, CR can't help you, and in any case this is way too broad for SO. Please read [ask], and make sure you read the [Guide to CR for SO users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788) if you're unfamiliar with CR's rulebook. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

***Object oriented design:*** use getters and setters for all fields is proper practice. If you want to be lazy, make all your fields public and they will be accessible from the object without getters or setters.

If you wish to access a variable throughout multiple methods in a class.

A) You'll can make a variable global

B) Create a local variable, and pass it as a parameter until you no longer need to use it.

```
public class Main { //All implementations stated above

    private Object globalObject;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object localObject;
        method1(localObject);

        method2ThatUsesGlobalObject();
    }
}
```

***Accessing variables between classes:***

A) Make a variable static

B) Pass it through method parameters, or constructor parameters

C) Use abstract classes or interfaces

Here are examples of the code usage I've stated

```
public abstract class JavaAbstractClass {
    public abstract Object giveMeThisObjectWhenINeedItThanks();
}

public interface JavaInterface { 
    Object giveMeThisObjectWhenINeedItThanks();
}

public class Main { //All implementations stated above

    public static Object object; //Accessible by Main.object everywhere

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object local;

        ClassOne class = new ClassOne();
        class.method1(local);

        new ClassWithInterface() {
            @Override
            public Object giveMeThisObjectWhenINeedItThanks() {
                    return local;
            }
        };

       new JavaAbstractClass() {
            @Override
            public Object giveMeThisObjectWhenINeedItThanks() {
                    return local;
            }
        };
    }
}
```